# " ImportError: cannot import name CaptchaFields " - Django

Tags: python, django, captcha, importerror

I cloned a ***working project*** from BitBucket and tried:
`python manage.py runserver`

I'm getting the following error:

> from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
>       ImportError: cannot import name CaptchaField

I did install captcha using `pip install captcha` and it installed without any error.
Following is my captcha folder ( *installation directory* ) contents

[image]

I tried installing  `simple-cpatcha` , `recaptcha` manually but didn't help.
I couldn't find `captcha` *zip file* to install it manually.

Comment: Did you also add `captcha` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings?

Comment: Yes I did (Actually, the settings file contained it _(I just cloned)_  )
The project works fine with my friends systems.

Comment: share your `setting.py` file.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share project files.  
But I guarantee that There is no problem with the code.  
Extremely sorry for that.  
But please Help me.

Comment: __I got it solved.__ I had Django 1.9.x actually. I removed it and installed Django 1.8.2. Also, I removed Anaconda _(This shouldn't affect the problem, but still stating)_  . Then I installed captcha, and it is working fine.  
Thanks.  
I'm not removing the Question because I think it might be helpful to others. This captcha is not much discussed on web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem.
Using `Django 1.8.2`, `Python 2.7` and `pip 7.0.1`
and command `pip install captcha` solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue by installing the following packages:

```
pip3 install captcha
pip3 install django-simple-captcha
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some problem on Mac OS with Python 3.7, Django 2.1, fixed by reinstall `django-simple-captcha`

`pip uninstall django-simple-captcha
pip install django-simple-captcha`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an integrated development environment like *pycharm* with a virtual environment, check if the correct package was installed. That did it for me. Go to the interpreter settings and check the installed package list. If the package `captcha` comes up, it is the WRONG package. Uninstall it and check the available packages list for `django-simple-captcha` and install that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import from the field like this

```
from rest_framework_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
```

that worked for me